# Wrap Divs when Content Box Size changes?

Tags: html, css

I have a content box that changes sizes depending on the source.

There is a Title and Info div underneath which is displayed horizontal inline.

This looks fine if the content box is large, but if small the Title and Info over extend.

How can I get the Title and Info to stack when the content box is smaller than the Title/Info width?

But not with resolution media queries, the browser size stays the same, only the box changes size.

https://jsfiddle.net/hphzh1ea/

**Large** (Good)

[image: Large]

**Small** (Over extended)

[image: Small]

**Small Stacked** (How it needs to look)

[image: Small Fix]

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="content">content</div>

  <div class="info">
    <div class="title">Title Title Title</div>
    <div class="description">info info info info info info info info info</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: gray;
}

.info {
  display: inline-block;
}
.title {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.description {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you were looking for a pure HTML/CSS solution, but maybe this simple jQuery script I wrote could help?

```
$(".container").find(function() {
  var contentWidth = $(".content").outerWidth();
  var infoWidth = $(".info").outerWidth();
  if (contentWidth < infoWidth){
    $(".description").css('display', 'block');
  }
});
```

Comment: That works pretty good, I'll probably use it. Let me see if anyone else has any css answers before accepting.